# Как сделать так чтобы нажатием одной кнопки, нажимались все кнопки с файлами и эти файлы скачивались

Tags: javascript

```
function allClick() {
 var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.button');
 for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
buttons[i].click();
   };/ищет кнопки после чего записывает их в одну переменную. нужно чтоб нажало все эти кнопки
<div class="buttons">
  <a onclick="" download href="2.jpeg">button</a>
  <a download href="1.jpeg” onclick="">button</a>
  </div>
```

Comment: Вы не определились javascript это или java?

Comment: .......javascript

Comment: А зачем тогда тег java?)

Answer (score 0):

[JSZip](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/)
Как понимаете, файлы должны сначала загрузиться, преобразовать, например в base64, и создать архив для сохранения.
Не проще ли по вашим файлам сделать архиватор серверным языком?